# is there any cisco-compatible ipsec+comp module?

Tags: cisco, ipsec, compression

I am looking for a waqy to establish an Ipsec tunnel(with lzs-compression enabled) between a cisco router and a host(using strongswan or sth else).
I can establish a tunnel without lzs-compression. but I need a way to support lzs or modules which are compatible with cisco's IPsec and compression.

Thanks.

Comment: I bit of googling indicates that lzs is not supported at all under linux, because it's patent-encumbered.